# Filtering spree products by size using elastic search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, spree

Here is my spree_elasticsearch_product_decorator.rb file where all search logic comes from
module Spree
  Product.class_eval do
    include Elasticsearch::Model

```
index_name Spree::ElasticsearchSettings.index
document_type 'spree_product'

mapping _all: {"index_analyzer" => "nGram_analyzer", "search_analyzer" => "whitespace_analyzer"} do
  indexes :name, type: 'multi_field' do
    indexes :name, type: 'string', analyzer: 'nGram_analyzer', boost: 100
    indexes :untouched, type: 'string', include_in_all: false, index: 'not_analyzed'
  end
  indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball'
  indexes :available_on, type: 'date', format: 'dateOptionalTime', include_in_all: false
  indexes :price, type: 'double'
  indexes :sku, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'
  indexes :taxon_ids, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'
  indexes :collection_ids, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'
  indexes :properties, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'
end

def as_indexed_json(options={})
  result = as_json({
    methods: [:price, :sku],
    only: [:available_on, :description, :name],
    include: {
      variants: {
        only: [:sku],
        include: {
          option_values: {
            only: [:name, :presentation]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
  result[:properties] = property_list unless property_list.empty?
  result[:taxon_ids] = taxons.map(&:self_and_ancestors).flatten.uniq.map(&:id) unless taxons.empty?
  result[:collection_ids] = collections.uniq.map(&:id) unless collections.empty?
  result
end

# Inner class used to query elasticsearch. The idea is that the query is dynamically build based on the parameters.
class Product::ElasticsearchQuery
  include ::Virtus.model

  attribute :from, Integer, default: 0
  attribute :price_min, Float
  attribute :price_max, Float
  attribute :properties, Hash
  attribute :query, String
  attribute :taxons, Array
  attribute :collections, Array
  attribute :browse_mode, Boolean
  attribute :sorting, String

  def to_hash
    q = { match_all: {} }
    unless query.blank? # nil or empty
      q = { query_string: { query: query, fields: ['name^5','description','sku'], default_operator: 'AND', use_dis_max: true } }
    end
    query = q

    and_filter = []
    unless @properties.nil? || @properties.empty?
      # transform properties from [{"key1" => ["value_a","value_b"]},{"key2" => ["value_a"]}
      # to { terms: { properties: ["key1||value_a","key1||value_b"] }
      #    { terms: { properties: ["key2||value_a"] }
      # This enforces "and" relation between different property values and "or" relation between same property values
      properties = @properties.map {|k,v| [k].product(v)}.map do |pair|
        and_filter << { terms: { properties: pair.map {|prop| prop.join("||")} } }
      end
    end

    sorting = case @sorting
    when "name_asc"
      [ {"name.untouched" => { order: "asc" }}, {"price" => { order: "asc" }}, "_score" ]
    when "name_desc"
      [ {"name.untouched" => { order: "desc" }}, {"price" => { order: "asc" }}, "_score" ]
    when "price_asc"
      [ {"price" => { order: "asc" }}, {"name.untouched" => { order: "asc" }}, "_score" ]
    when "price_desc"
      [ {"price" => { order: "desc" }}, {"name.untouched" => { order: "asc" }}, "_score" ]
    when "score"
      [ "_score", {"name.untouched" => { order: "asc" }}, {"price" => { order: "asc" }} ]
    else
      [ {"name.untouched" => { order: "asc" }}, {"price" => { order: "asc" }}, "_score" ]
    end

    # facets
    facets = {
      price: { statistical: { field: "price" } },
      properties: { terms: { field: "properties", order: "count", size: 100 } }, 
      taxon_ids: { terms: { field: "taxon_ids", size: 1000000 } },
      collection_ids: { terms: { field: "collection_ids", size: 1000000 } }
    }

    # basic skeleton
    result = {
      min_score: 0.1,
      query: { filtered: {} },
      sort: sorting,
      from: from,
      facets: facets
    }

    # add query and filters to filtered
    result[:query][:filtered][:query] = query
    # taxon and property filters have an effect on the facets
    and_filter << { terms: { taxon_ids: taxons } } unless taxons.empty?
    and_filter << { terms: { collection_ids: collections } } unless collections.empty?
    # only return products that are available
    and_filter << { range: { available_on: { lte: "now" } } }
    result[:query][:filtered][:filter] = { "and" => and_filter } unless and_filter.empty?

    # add price filter outside the query because it should have no effect on facets
    if price_min && price_max && (price_min < price_max)
      result[:filter] = { range: { price: { gte: price_min, lte: price_max } } }
    end

    result
  end
end

private

def property_list
  product_properties.map{|pp| "#{pp.property.name}||#{pp.value}"}
end
```

I need somehow implement size filter

For each size I have a Spree::Variant which belongs_to Spree::Product and stores value of size in name column, e.g
Spree::Variant.name = "13 US"

How can I sort products by variants using elasticsearch ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hello. I'm a fellow spree user, but I can't possibly answer your question because you're way ahead of me. Do you have any guidance for implementing elastic search and getting to the point that you are at now? Any links on elastic search in rails that you recommend? Sorry that this won't help your question.

Comment: Hi! That is not my code :) Check [spree_elasticsearch](https://github.com/javereec/spree_elasticsearch)

Comment: whats the gem youre using to connect to ElasticSearch?

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails